# Linq syntax required for string array to string conversion

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I've the list of selected files in a array from particular folder.

```
String[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Target, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I required to convert all of this files into the string variable and each line append with "\n" character  with help of LINQ. I can do it as like below with help of looping but i required in LINQ Syntax.

```
String strFileName = string.Empty;

for ( int i = 0; i < allfiles.Length ; i++)
  strFileName = strFileName + "\n" + allfiles[1] ;
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `allfiles[i]`

Comment: Your above code can't solve your problem.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Obviously. If it could, why would he be asking here?

Comment: Thanks to all. Your answers helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, i would use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) instead, so you don't need to wait until all files are read. Then you can use [`string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allFileNames)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> allFileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Target, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string strFileNames  = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allFileNames);
```

Answer (score 5):

Easy enough

```
String.Join("\n",allFiles)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Linq to do that, you can use the `String.Join` method as illustrated in Jamiec's answer.

Now, if you really want to do it with Linq, you could use `Aggregate`:

```
string strFileName = allfiles.Aggregate("", (acc, file) => acc + "\n" + file);
```

Or better, using a `StringBuilder`:

```
string strFileName = allfiles.Aggregate(
                                  new StringBuilder(),
                                  (acc, file) => acc.AppendLine(file),
                                  acc => acc.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's **required** to use LINQ:

```
var result = allFiles.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                                (sb, s) => sb.AppendLine(s),
                                sb => sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need linq for that. Just use simple string.Join() method.

```
string.Join("\n",allfiles);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Linq to do this you can use the string.Join() method instead.

```
String strFileName = string.Join("\n", allfiles);
```

Comment: There is [no overload of `String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.concat.aspx) which takes a `string` and an `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score -1):

Following should work

```
String.Join(delimiter,stringArray);
```